# Java 8 LocalDateTime - How to Get All Times Between Two Dates

Tags: java, date, java-stream, iterable, localdate

I want to generate a list of dates + times between two dates in the format `2018-01-31T17:20:30Z` (or `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"` ) in 60 second increments.

So far I've been able to generate all dates between two dates using a `LocalDate` object:

```
public class DateRange implements Iterable<LocalDate> {


  private final LocalDate startDate;
  private final LocalDate endDate;

  public DateRange(LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate) {
    //check that range is valid (null, start < end)
    this.startDate = startDate;
    this.endDate = endDate;
  }


@Override
public Iterator<LocalDate> iterator() {

    return stream().iterator();
}

public Stream<LocalDate> stream() {
    return Stream.iterate(startDate, d -> d.plusDays(1))
                 .limit(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(startDate, endDate) + 1);
  }
```

}

Given a start and end date this generates an `Iterable` of all dates in between.

However, I would like modify this so that it generates each time in 60 second increments using `LocalDateTime` object (i.e, instead of generating one value per day it would generate 1440 values as there are 60 minutes per hour times 24 hrs per day assuming the start and end time was only one day)

Thanks

Comment: Tip: Add the *ThreeTen-Extra* library to your project to use the [`LocalDateRange`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/LocalDateRange.html) class rather than roll your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the **LocalDate** to **LocalDateTime** and **plusDays** to **plusMinutes** and **DAYS** to **MINUTES**.

```
    public class DateTimeRange implements Iterable<LocalDateTime> {


      private final LocalDateTime startDateTime;
      private final LocalDateTime endDateTime;

      public DateTimeRange(LocalDateTime startDateTime, LocalDateTime endDateTime) {
        //check that range is valid (null, start < end)
        this.startDateTime = startDateTime;
        this.endDateTime = endDateTime;
      }


      @Override
      public Iterator<LocalDateTime> iterator() {
         return stream().iterator();
      }

      public Stream<LocalDateTime> stream() {
         return Stream.iterate(startDateTime, d -> d.plusMinutes(1))
                     .limit(ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(startDateTime, endDateTime) + 1);
      }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks. If I modify code to generate timestamp every 5 hrs this causes issue @:   `public Stream<LocalDateTime> stream() {
         return Stream.iterate(startDate, d -> d.plusMinutes(300))
                     .limit( ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(startDate, endDate ) + 1);
      }`   For example, if I pass `DateRange(LocalDateTime.of(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0), **LocalDateTime.now()**)` it generates all the way through yr **2341** instead of today's date. Changing   `...MINUTES.between(startDate, endDate ) + 1);` to   `...MINUTES.between(startDate, endDate ) + 300);` did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 6):

Why, just the same:

```
public Stream<LocalDateTime> stream() {
    return Stream.iterate(startDate, d -> d.plusMinutes(1))
                 .limit(ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(startDate, endDate) + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

<s>I'm not sure where the problem is so maybe I misunderstood the question, but I would go with the following:</s>

EDIT: See @isaac answer instead

```
public Stream<LocalDateTime> stream() {
    return Stream.iterate(startDate.atStartOfDay(), d -> d.plus(60, ChronoUnit.SECONDS))
        .limit(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(startDate, endDate) + 1);
}
```

Comment: DAYS should be converted to MINUTES

Comment: Ah yes you are right, anyway @isaac answer seems to be the right one